# Does the first cohomology of the Hodge bundle over the moduli space of curves $M_{g,n}$ vanish?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I know the Leray spectral sequence relates this to the cohomology of the relative dualizing sheaf, but I don't know anything about the cohomology of either of these sheaves.